# Sencha Touch: unable to call superclass error

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I've been trying to extend Ext.Panel with the following code (in app/view/viewport.js):

```
App.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    fullscreen: true,

    initComponent: function() {
        App.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

this code is called from (app/app.js):

```
App = new Ext.Application({
    name: 'App',
    launch: function() {
        this.launched = true;
        this.mainLaunch();
    },
    mainLaunch: function() {
        if (!device || !this.launched) {return;}
        this.views.viewport = new this.views.Viewport();
    }
});
```

The entire thing works just fine on the desktop, but when phonegap (0.9.6) is thrown into the equation, and deployed on an Android device, I get the following error (in LogCat):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'superclass' of undefined at file:///android_asset/www/app/views/viewport.js
```

I've been investigating this thing for hours without any progress at all!
Your help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PhoneGap on Android makes an object called "app" of its own that is conflicting with your namespace. Rename your "App" to something else and it should work.

See http://www.codesta.com/blog/2011/5/23/sencha-touchphonegap-tips-and-tricks.html